# Count how many of '/' are in one line while reading from files

Tags: python, split

So I have a script that goes through all files within one folder.
Those are .txt files that contain inside some paths.

Structure inside is like this, each file has several paths inside and their structure (depth) is not the same:

```
folder1/folder2/folder3/.../module
folder1/folder2/folder5/folder6/module
```

What would the way to split each line as i? And later use each i for something else like:

```
line = folder1/folder2/folder3/.../module
i = line.split('/')
```

then I would have i = folder1, next itteraiton i = folder2, etc...

Comment: `line.split('/')` will provide a list with string elements separated by the `/`. What's the point of assigning the value to `i` first?

Comment: The title ask count of `/`s. But you are asking for something else. What is the exact problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can split your string like this:

```
line = "folder1/folder2/folder3/.../module"
folders = line.split("/")
```

Folders is a list that contains all the folder names:

```
print(folders)
>>> ['folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3', '...', 'module']
```

If you want the number of '/'s in the string do:

```
count = len(folders)-1
print(count)
>>> 4
```